What should you do if you are legally an employee, but paid as a contractor [Canada]
My partner works as an independent contractor doing digital marketing and social media management for a company that handles businesses' online presences (websites, google business profiles, etc.)
They were hired as a contractor, and asked to sign a contract for the job, with a schedule attached detailing piece work rates for various types of job activities. Reading this contract, you could be reasonably happy that this is a contract position. It also says that this contract is not affected by other correspondence/conversations. (Foreshadowing)
However, a few months ago, the company sent out an email to contractors saying that all hours worked on jobs had to be tracked in ClickUp, and that you would NOT be paid your piece work rate if you did not track hours for that client. To me tracking hours while working piecework, is a form of a control that only an employer gets to have, and it's not anywhere in the contract that was signed. Of course, if someone is contracted HOURLY, it goes without saying that they'd need share the hours worked.
So, my question is, how should my partner let their boss know that the change that's being demanded would make them their employer? Alternatively, what's a professional way to say "that's not in my job description?" without pissing them off to the point they'd consider replacing them?

Post-script, in case anyone has opinions on whether my partner is a contractor. Technically, this part doesn't belong on workplace.SE, but I'm curious to hear what you all think.
Here in Canada, this is what our tax authority says about who is and is not considered a contractor
Indicators showing that the worker is an employee


The relationship is one of subordination. The payer will often direct, scrutinize, and effectively control many elements of how and when the work is carried out ✔
The payer controls the worker with respect to both the results of the work and the method used to do the work ✔
The payer chooses and controls the method and amount of pay. Salary negotiations may still take place in an employer-employee relationship ✔
The payer decides what jobs the worker will do ✔
The payer chooses to listen to the worker's suggestions but has the final word ✔
The worker requires permission to work for other payers while working for this payer ❌
Where the schedule is irregular, priority on the worker's time is an indication of control over the worker 
The worker receives training or direction from the payer on how to do the work. The overall work environment between the worker and the payer is one of subordination 


Indicators showing that the worker is a self-employed individual


A self-employed individual usually works independently ✔
The worker does not have anyone overseeing their activities ❌
The worker is usually free to work when and for whom they choose and may provide their services to different payers at the same time ✔
The worker can accept or refuse work from the payer ❌
The working relationship between the payer and the worker does not present a degree of continuity, loyalty, security, subordination, or integration, all of which are generally associated with an employer-employee relationship ❌



How do they pay if they don't know how many hours were spent on a job? Are they paid a set rate per period?

Most kinds of contractors are paid hourly and track hours so this is not a priori an employee distinction.  It is strange to track hours when paid by piece but there is nothing wrong with it, I could see value in the metrics to the company.

@Kilisi The pay is not hourly. They are paid a flat rate based on how many accounts they manage.

@mxyzplk Sure, it could be valuable to the company, but withholding pay contrary to contract is not ok in my book. I guess I should clarify that piece work (or flat rate) pay should preclude you from tracking time, especially as a contractor.

You are making the largest assumption when you say "should preclude." That may be your preference, but I would be surprised if there is anything forbidding them from asking for that information. Assuming you want the contract, I suggest cooperating. If the privacy matters more to you than being paid, then walk away. Or say no and then find out whether they want to keep you on contract. Your choice.

Has your partner suggested that the additional administrative work should be covered by a revised - and renegotiated - contract (Ie. make the point it's not in the current one)? That's how a contractor could respond and retain designation as a contractor.

related - https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/101913/what-are-some-of-the-legal-consequences-of-hiring-full-time-employees-as-indepen

I routinely require my contractors to document how many hours they worked on a project so I can hold them responsible for making sure they don’t go over budget. Of course I require the project manager, to provide this information, not individual employees. How they get the information is up to them, you can probably guess, they how they document how many hours was billed to a project in a week.

Maybe it's my pedantic reading of what you wrote, but I don't see any control here other than a refusal to pay unless your partner keeps track of what hours they worked for each client. Does this mean your partner is no longer being paid for piecework and is being paid per hour? Or are they still being paid for piecework, but the employer likes to keep track of who was working on what?

"how should my partner let their boss know that the change that's being demanded would make them their employer"  I wouldn't go there based on your opinion/interpretation.  You should discuss with a lawyer or qualified government agent before making that claim.

@ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere: be careful when saying you want to renegotiate your contract. You may not like the outcome.

@keshlam there's no need for a renegotiated contract, just an addendum stating that on occasion, company X will require the contractor to do administrative duties, and then outline some of the duties, and what they should be paid for it.

@cdkMoose I agree. The purpose of the question is not whether they are a contractor, but instead what action is necessary IF they are a contractor

@Donald there's no way to go over budget... They are only compensated for making a minimum number of ads or social posts per month, on a mandated schedule. They could spend 400 hours in a month on 1 client and have no impact on budget. If someone is contracted HOURLY, it goes without saying that they'd need share the hours worked. But in that case, I would invoice at a certain rate for admin tasks, if the hours needed to be tracked outside of my invoice. I've done this personally.

I'm curious why this question was closed? I made sure to specific that the focus of the question aligned with the title: "What should you do if you are legally an employee, but paid as a contractor"
And I clarified that I am seeking advice on how to word a letter. The mention of the legal aspects were only intended for those willing to discuss it in their answer. Would it be appropriate to edit the question to remove any mention of the legal aspects? While I agree this is a difficult question, I don't think that it should be closed for new answers. There is someone out there who can benefit.

@inund8, Personally, I don't know what can be done legally speaking. But your partner needs to find other clients. His leverage in this negotiation is only as good as his ability to walk away. Also, he needs to draft his own contracts with his new clients. Search for contract-killer examples on github. Or search for Leon Noel on youtube. If he continues to let this client encroach on his independence, that client will eventually use the information he inputs to squeeze his pay even more. And instead of getting increased pay every year, he'll receive a decrease every year. This is not good.


So, my question is, how should my partner let their boss know that the change that's being demanded would make them their employer?

You should not go this route without consulting an employment lawyer. Making a legal statement like this dicey and the interpretation of the law is complicated. I also don't see what that would gain you. Does your partner WANT to become an employee?

Alternatively, what's a professional way to say "that's not in my job description?"

You can say: "this constitutes a unilateral change to the existing contract".

without pissing them off to the point they'd consider replacing them?

Probably not possible. The company has a new policy and its rolling it out. They probably anticipated some amount of discontent and potential attrition but they are apparently fine with that. This is most likely a "get with the program or get off" proposition.
This is indeed "a unilateral change to the existing contract". That's not fun but not unusual either. Your choices are

Accept it
Try to negotiate some changes (extra pay for admin overhead, higher rate, etc)
Refuse the change: in this case the contract terminates and your partner needs to find new work.


making a legal statement like that to your contracted employer will almost certainly result in no longer being a contractor.

I like how you broke this down very simply and clearly. This is a worthy answer, but I usually wait a week before handing out a checkmark

One typo: I think you meant employment lawyer.

@keshlam: fixed

@TigerGuy that's fine if it's because you end up being an employee! Less so if it's because your contract is terminated
